# Add ranking variable to database with MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, join, sql-update, window-functions

I have a database with the following structure:

```
ID   GROUP   VALUE   RANK
2      1      999     0
1      1      888     0
3      2      777     0
4      2      111     0
```

I need to update the "RANK" column by ranking IDs according to the "VALUE" column and grouping by the "GROUP" column. Basically, in the example above, I should end up with:

```
ID   GROUP   VALUE   RANK
2      1      999     1
1      1      888     2
3      2      777     1
4      2      111     2
```

I tried following another answer and slightly changing the query:

```
SET @r=0;
UPDATE `table` SET `RANK` = @r:= (@r+1) ORDER BY `VALUE` DESC;
```

to

```
SET @r=0;
UPDATE `table` SET `RANK` = @r:= (@r+1) PARTITION BY `GROUP` ORDER BY `VALUE` DESC;
```

but this throws an error. Alternatively, this approach produces the correct ranking:

```
SELECT `ID`,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY `GROUP` ORDER BY `VALUE`) as `RANK`
FROM table;
```

but it does not update the "RANK" column in the database. I slightly prefer the second solution to the first one, but how can I save the output of the query to the RANK column?

Comment: You need 2 user-defined variables. First stores `group` of previous row and 2nd is used for `rank` calculation.

Comment: PS. Does your server is 5.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the table to your last query (also use `DESC` in the `ORDER BY` clause) in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE tablename t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY `GROUP` ORDER BY `VALUE` DESC) AS `RANK`
  FROM tablename
) r ON r.ID = t.ID
SET t.`RANK` = r.`RANK`;
```

Comment: Thanks this works if I change the query column name to "RANK2" as "RANK" is already taken in the original database

Comment: @EadieHamilton or select only id and RANK() in the subquery. See my edited query.